# python - Game Rock Paper Scissors with class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I've created the "Rock Paper Scissors" with class
I've  created an if statement inside the  "def Game(self)"
Could you please what is wrong with my code , I'm guessing it'd related to the "elif " ...

The problem is that the values of the "player" and "computer" are NOT pass inside the "elif "

```
import random

possible_actions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
computer = random.choice(possible_actions)


class Game_Rock_Paper_Scissors:
    def __init__(self, player, computer):
        self.player = player
        self.computer = computer


    def Game(self):
        print("Starting to play")
        if player == computer:
            print("Tie!")
        elif player == "Rock":
            if computer == "Paper":
                return "You lose!{1} covers{0}" .format(self.computer,self.player)
            else:
                return "You win!{0} smashes{1}" .format(self.player ,self.computer)
        elif player == "Paper":
            if computer == "Scissors":
                return "You lose!{1} cut {0}" .format(self.computer,self.player)
            else:
                return "You win! {0} covers {1}" .format(self.player ,self.computer)
        elif player == "Scissors":
            if computer == "Rock":
                return "You lose...{1} smashes {0}" .format(self.computer,self.player)
            else:
                return "You win!{1} cut {0}" .format(self.player ,self.computer)
        print("Game end")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    player = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")

    if player!="rock" and player!="paper" and player!="scissors":
            print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")

    else:
        print(f"\nYou chose {player}, computer chose {computer}.\n")
        playing = Game_Rock_Paper_Scissors(player ,computer)
        playing.Game()
```

Comment: You seem to be switching between globals and attributes haphazardly. Attributes of the instance `self` are available as `self.player` and `self.computer`.

Comment: Also `"paper"` is a different string from `"Paper"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just as @khelwood mentioned there are two things wrong with your code.

1. case of rock, paper, etc
2. Interchangeable use of instance and local variable

The correct code is below:

```
import random

possible_actions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
computer = random.choice(possible_actions)


class Game_Rock_Paper_Scissors:
    def __init__(self, player, computer):
        self.player = player
        self.computer = computer


    def Game(self):
        print("Starting to play")
        if self.player == self.computer:
            print("Tie!")
        elif self.player == "rock":
            if self.computer == "paper":
                return "You lose!{1} covers {0}" .format(self.computer,self.player)
            else:
                return "You win!{0} smashes {1}" .format(self.player ,self.computer)
        elif self.player == "paper":
            if self.computer == "scissors":
                return "You lose!{1} cut {0}" .format(self.computer,self.player)
            else:
                return "You win! {0} covers {1}" .format(self.player ,self.computer)
        elif self.player == "scissors":
            if self.computer == "rock":
                return "You lose...{1} smashes {0}" .format(self.computer,self.player)
            else:
                return "You win!{1} cut {0}" .format(self.player ,self.computer)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    player = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")

    if player!="rock" and player!="paper" and player!="scissors":
            print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")

    else:
        print(f"\nYou chose {player}, computer chose {computer}.\n")
        playing = Game_Rock_Paper_Scissors(player ,computer)
        print(playing.Game())
        print("Game end")
```